# Подключение заголовочных файлов

Tags: devc++, c++

Добрый день, сообщество!

*Очередной глупый вопрос.*

В проекте есть два файла - **Bow.h** (заголовочный файл) и **Bow.cpp** (в нем вся реализация из Bow.h). Вписываю в **Bow.cpp** строку **#include "Bow.h"**, тем самым пытаясь связать эти два модуля в один. Но компилятор выдает ошибку: *In file included from Bow.cpp*. Без этого ругается, что класс **Bow** не объявлен. Тоже самое происходит, когда я пытаюсь подключить что-то к главному модулю.

Направьте меня, пожалуйста, на путь истинный.

Comment: In file included from Bow.cpp и все? Что-то еще пишет?

Comment: @teanЫЧ, вопрос не глупый, а безобразно задан. 

Вы наверное понимаете, что все дело в содержимом файлов, точнее тех их строк, на которые ругается компилятор.

А мы ведь их не видим...

Comment: @avp, спасибо! вот это я называю "направить". Я просто с с++ впервые связался, и не освоился еще. Компилятор выкинул сообщение _In file included from Bow.cpp._, и показывал на строку __#include "Bow.h"__ и поэтому я подумал, что проблема в подключении. Но прочитав ваш комментарий я понял, какой я идиот, и быстро нашел ошибку - после public не поставил двоеточие (привычка после Delphi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего забыли заключить Ваш `.h` файл в защитную оболочку:)

```
#ifndef __BOW_H_
#define __BOW_H_
#pragma once

// здесь бывшее содержимое bow.h

#endif
```

можно конечно и без `#pragma once`. Это будет работать на всех компиляторах. На новых можно просто добавить `#pragma once` в самое начало. `__BOW_H_` - это константа, которая обычно выбирается на основе имени файла, что бы быть уникальной.

Comment: нет, была ошибка в коде, но компилятор отмечал строку с определением, и это сбило меня с толку. теперь буду знать. А защитные оболочки мне еще предстоит изучить :)